# Kotlin Exposed Custom Column Modularization

Tags: kotlin, dao, kotlin-exposed

I have a Kotlin Exposed DAO-based database set up and would like to clean up
repeated column names.

For example, lets say I have a table that looks like:

```
// Yes, super contrived, not my real use case. Just an minimal example
class ColourComponentTable : IntIdTable() {
    val name = text("name")
}

class ColourTable : IntIdTable() {
    val name = text("name")
    val r = reference("r", ColourComponentTable)
    val g = reference("g", ColourComponentTable)
    val b = reference("b", ColourComponentTable)
}

// Maybe this is for a colour theme or something
class ColourBasisTable : IntIdTable() {
    val name = text("name")

    // primary colours
    val r1 = reference("r1", ColourTable)
    val g1 = reference("g1", ColourTable)
    val b1 = reference("b1", ColourTable)

    // backup colours
    val r2 = reference("r2", ColourTable)
    val g2 = reference("g2", ColourTable)
    val b2 = reference("b2", ColourTable)
}

// Objects
class ColourComponent(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<ColourComponent>(ColourComponentTable)
    var name by ColourComponentTable.name
}

class Colour(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<Colour>(ColourTable)
    var name by ColourTable.name
    var r by ColourComponent referencedOn ColourTable.r
    var g by ColourComponent referencedOn ColourTable.g
    var b by ColourComponent referencedOn ColourTable.b
}

class ColourBasis(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<ColourBasis>(ColourBasisTable)
    var name by ColourBasisTable.name
    var r1 by Colour referencedOn ColourBasisTable.r1
    var g1 by Colour referencedOn ColourBasisTable.g1
    var b1 by Colour referencedOn ColourBasisTable.b1
    var r2 by Colour referencedOn ColourBasisTable.r2
    var g2 by Colour referencedOn ColourBasisTable.g2
    var b2 by Colour referencedOn ColourBasisTable.b2
}
```

I would like to 'wrap' the repeated similar columns in a custom column type. So
far I have tried the equivalent of:

```
class ColourComponentTable : IntIdTable() {
    val name = text("name")
}

class RGBColumn< R : Comparable<R>, T : Comparable<T>>(
    suffix: String = "",
    parent: IdTable<R>,
    ref: IdTable<T>
) {
    val r = parent.text("r" + suffix)
    val g = parent.text("g" + suffix)
    val b = parent.text("b" + suffix)
}

class RGBObject<Target : IntEntity, R : Comparable<R>, T : Comparable<T>>(
    ref : RGBColumn<R, T>
) {
    var r by Target referencedOn ref.r
    var g by Target referencedOn ref.g
    var b by Target referencedOn ref.b
}

class ColourTable : IntIdTable() {
    val name = text("name")
    val c = RGBColumn("", this, ColourComponentTable)
}

class ColourBasisTable : IntIdTable() {
    val name = text("name")

    // primary colours
    val c1 = RGBColumn("1", this, ColourTable)

    // backup colours
    val c2 = RGBColumn("2", this, ColourTable)
}

// Objects
class ColourComponent(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<ColourComponent>(ColourComponentTable)
    var name by ColourComponentTable.name
}

class Colour(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<Colour>(ColourTable)
    var name by ColourTable.name
    var c by RGBObject<ColourComponent> referencedOn ColourTable.c
}

class ColourBasis(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<ColourBasis>(ColourBasisTable)
    var name by ColourBasisTable.name
    var c1 by RGBObject<Colour> referencedOn ColourBasisTable.c1
    var c2 by RGBObject<Colour> referencedOn ColourBasisTable.c2
}
```

Of course this doesn't work. I feel like I am close though. In particular I feel
like I should be able to get the custom Column/Object pair to work. I have tried
all sorts of combinations of possible generic arguments to the `RGBObject`, but
none of them will get the code to compile.

Any ideas what I'm missing? Is this even possible?